# Arrays in J: indexing from one into another

Tags: filtering, lookup, j, apl, dyalog

Using J I am trying to do something similar to the following example shown on page 128 of [Mastering Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/uploads/documents/MasteringDyalogAPL.pdf#page=150) by Bernard Legrand (2009). I have not been able to find a direct conversion of this code into J, which is what I want.

Here's the example:

> ```
> BHCodes ← 83 12 12 83 43 66 50 81 12 83 14 66 etc...
> BHAmounts ← 609 727 458 469 463 219 431 602 519 317 663 631...
> ```
>
> #### 13.3.2 - First Question
>
> We would like to focus on some selected countries (14, 43, 50, 37, and 66) and
>   calculate the total amount of their sales. Let’s first identify which
>   items of BHCodes are relevant:
>
> ```
>       Selected ← 14 43 50 37 66
>       BHCodes  ∊ Selected
> 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0     ⇦ Identifies sales in the selected countries only.
> ```
>
> Then we can apply this filter to the amounts, and add them up:
>
> ```
>      (BHCodes ∊ Selected) / BHAmounts
> 463 219 431 663 631 421
>      +/ (BHCodes ∊ Selected) / BHAmounts
> 2828
> ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
+/ (BHCodes e. Selected) # BHAmounts
```

For your purposes here, APL's `∊` is J's `e.` ([Member (In)](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help806/dictionary/dedot.htm)) and APL's `/` is J's `#` ([Copy](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help806/dictionary/d400.htm)).

Notes:

1. APL's `∊` and J's `e.` are not completely equivalent as APL's `∊` looks for every *element* in its left argument among the *elements* of its right argument, while J's `e.` looks for every *major cell*. of its left argument in the *major cells* of its right argument.
2. APL's `/` and J's `#` are not completely equivalent as APL's `/` operates along the trailing axis while J's # operates along the leading axis. APL does have `⌿` though, which operates along the leading axis. There are more nuances, but they are not relevant here.